# How to keep a random-size byte array in a Rust struct?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to do this, but it doesn't work:

```
struct Pack {
  data: Box<[u8]>
}
fn foo() {
  let mut p = Pack {
    data: Box::new(**b"Hello!")
  };
  p.data.set(b"Bye!");
}
```

I'm getting:

```
error[E0614]: type `[u8; 6]` cannot be dereferenced
  --> foo
   |
30 |         data: Box::new(**b"Hello!")
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[u8]` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> foo
    |
30  |         data: Box::new(**b"Hello!")
    |               ^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Why not use a `Vec<u8>` instead?

Comment: @mousetail I don't mind at all. Please, suggest a working alternative with `Vec<u8>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a `Vec` instead:

```rs
struct Pack {
  data: Vec<u8>
}
fn foo() {
  let mut p = Pack {
    data: b"Hello!".to_vec()
  };
  p.data=b"Bye!".to_vec();
}
```

A vector is just like a array, except it's size is dynamic and you can resize it at runtime. See [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) for more details.